# how to catch the system broadcast BOOT_COMPLETED, my program just doesn't work?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I writed a small program to catch the system broadcast `BOOT_COMPLETED`, but it just doesn't work:

```
package com.alex.app.testsysreboot;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("my_tag", "system reboot completed.......");
    }    
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.alex.app.testsysreboot"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</manifest>
```

I closed the AVD, and then clicked the button "run" in Eclipse, and the Eclipse started a new AVD, but after the system boot, I just cannot see the log in the LogCat...

Comment: you can checkout my complete example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690350/android-start-service-on-boot/7690600#7690600)

Comment: my program is more simple than yours. i don't want to start a service, but just output one Log using Log.i(xxxxx), it just dosen't work, i concerted my program to API level 3, then it cannot be installed on the SD card, it still does't work. could you run my program in ur environment, thanks in advance...

Comment: Ok I will try which version you are using 3.0 or 2.2?

Comment: i used 2.2 first, it doesn't work, and then i changed to lower version ---1.5, but it still does not ...

Comment: Check my complete answer, I tested it and it works fine. Hope it works for you too.

Comment: No problem, if you still face problem let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well I tried this and it Works for me,

```
public class Autostart extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
    {
        Log.i("Autostart", "**********started************");
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pack.saltriver" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <receiver android:name=".Autostart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add

```
android:enabled="true" 
android:exported="true"
```

AND

make sure that the app is not installed on the SD card - IIRC apps installed there don't receive that `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

Another point is that devices with "Fast Boot" enabled (like several HTC devices) (sometimes?) don't send `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

Since Android 3.1+ there is some more weirdness regarding `BOOT_COMPLETED` relating to "very first start of an app" - see http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html

A working sample project with source see https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemEvents/OnBoot

From http://arthurfmay.blogspot.com/2011/06/broadcastreceiver-bootcompleted-and.html

> So instead, from Eclipse I just went into the Android SDK and AVD
>   Manager (under the Window Menu) and started the emulator from there. I
>   did this of course after loading the app into the emulator. I start
>   the emulator and my BroadcastReceiver on boot works just fine. There
>   was no need to go to running the emulator at the command line.

Another working sample can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7690600/847363).

Comment: but in the SDK documents, i found the following words: the presence of at least one filter implies that the broadcast receiver is intended to receive intents broadcast by the system or other applications, so the default value is "true".  i have specified the intent-filter, so the default value should be true. after i added them, it still doesn't work......by the way,how could i know whether i have istalled the App in the SD card in an AVD?? thanks in advance....

Comment: @CyberRusher added link to a working sample project... if that does not work then you have hit one of the cases I describe in my answer...

Comment: @CyberRusher for AVD see http://arthurfmay.blogspot.com/2011/06/broadcastreceiver-bootcompleted-and.html

Comment: ok, thank you, but i am in China, the Government's "Greate Fire Wall" just blocked me from accessing the website, Fuxx the Government....

Comment: it still doesn't work, the goole SDK document says the Apps can be installed  on SD card after API leve8, but what i use is only 3 .......i have checked a lot of topics on it both in Einglish and chinese, but it seems that just no body konws how to catch the BOOT_COMPLETED correctly.....