# How can I replace an app which receive an intent send by an physical button in android 4.4?

Tags: android

I'm a new developer of Android app. I have a smartphone with **Android 4.4** and it has an extra physical button. when you press the button, it sends an intent, and one app named "AAA" receive this intent and start to run the app.

I need to implement an app "BBB" which replace this app "AAA". As I am a newcomer in the area of developing app android, can anybody tell me the easiest way to replace this app "AAA" with app "BBB"?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume the implementation of this button is similar as Android's Home button, we can use the same approach to override it.

For example, here's an activity declaration with an [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving) to receive a MAIN intent when the Home button is pressed:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <!-- The following two intent-filters are the key to set homescreen -->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In case you need, [there are plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841686/how-to-make-a-launcher) of discussions for the Home Button case.

Then, you would need be to figure out what are the action being used for your button and then use a very similar piece of code on your activity declaration.

Comment: Hi, Roberto. Thank you for your replay. I get the app works with the button. but when i restart the device, it doesn't work. then i need to reinstall the app, it work again, but after restart, it doesn't work again. Could you tell me how can i do?

Comment: Instead of reinstalling, did you try just running the app after reboot ?. If that works, what you need to do is to use RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED  action like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277207/how-to-catch-the-system-broadcast-boot-completed-my-program-just-doesnt-work

Comment: i'm trying the program, but i doesn't work. i mean, after i reboot the device, i can run the app from launcher, but i can't run it by pressing the button. My app just have an activity of opening a web page.