# Android. Reboot my BroadCast receiver. Not working.

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, reboot

How to start a service in android using nested class when mobile is switched ON?

I have the package contains nested class.

package Name

**com.android**

1. MainActivity
2. BroadCastReceiver

I am trying to reboot my BroadCast receiver. But it doesn't work (getting Failed). I don't know if the reason is, because of any problems for nested classes.

```
 <receiver android:name="ConnectionReceiver"></receiver> 

<receiver android:name="com.android.MainActivity .BroadCastReceiver "> 
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690350/android-start-service-on-boot/7690600#7690600

Comment: Thank you poptani.i didnt use sevice class.What s problem in my code

Comment: Well you can just remove service from my code and just check it yourself. Atleast you have a working example now, isn't it?

Comment: sir i cannot start the class from broadcast receiver

Comment: First of all don't use "sir", [come here to discuss](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="onchip.automobile.caraccessory1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >    

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <receiver 
            android:name=".Onchip_BroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>            
        </receiver>

        <service 
            android:name=".Onchip_BackgroundService">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="onchip.automobile.caraccessory1.BACKGROUND_SERVICE" />                
            </intent-filter>            
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Onchip_BroadcastReceiver.java**

```
package onchip.automobile.caraccessory1;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class Onchip_BroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("onchip.automobile.caraccessory1.BACKGROUND_SERVICE");        
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }   
}
```

**Onchip_BackgroundService.java**

```
package onchip.automobile.caraccessory1;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Onchip_BackgroundService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Onchip_BackgroundService Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Onchip_BackgroundService Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Onchip_BackgroundService Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }      

}
```

Comment: ya inside only .i called like this receiver = new ConnectionReceiver();

registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

Comment: please see the example at link given, you will understand.

Comment: did you used same code or modified ? because i used same code its working for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6847/discussion-between-leema-rose-and-yugandhar-babu)

Answer (score 0):

R u having BroadcastReceiver as nested class. if yes dont do this.

1)if you have receiver as nested class, register it in activity dynamically, do not register in manifest

2) if you are registering it in manifest , make separate class for Receiver.

Comment: i register in dynamically only

Comment: you already registerred it here <receiver android:name="com.android.MainActivity .BroadCastReceiver "> 
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver>

Comment: if you added it in manifest with action,, that means you registered it for that action.. New to Android!!!?

Comment: i register dynamically receiver = new ConnectionReceiver(); registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));