# android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED doesn't get fired on boot

Tags: android, broadcast

I have a BroadcastReceiver that i'm trying to detect when the system boot is completed but the Receiver doesn't get fired, or nothing in LogCat, any idea?

AndroidManifest

```
<!--  SIM Card Receiver -->

<receiver android:name=".SIMChangeNotifierActivity" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"> 
    <intent-filter android:priority="1001"> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver

```
public class SIMChangeNotifierActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {    

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
      if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))
      {
         Log.e("TAG", "Boot completed"); 
          }
}
```

Comment: add permission in the manifest for BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: Did you run one of your activities first? http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/05/boot-completed-regression.html

Comment: The BOOT_COMPLETED did the trick! thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7690600/726863

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just declare in your manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```