# how to start service in android without an activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

i am beginner at android. I have two class, and first class is

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{}
```

And the second class is

```
public class SMS extends Activity{}
```

All I want to do that : when I get an SMS, start activity and do something. But i want to use "service" instead of "activity". I mean when application start, then start service without activity.

is this possible ?

Comment: you have to extend your activity class to service and satrt the service by broadcast reciver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start your Service from SmsReceiver   as:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      if(action.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
        //action for sms received

           // start service here
          Intent intent=new Intent(context,Your_Service.class);
          context.startService(intent);

      }
      else {

      }     
   }
}
```

and make sure you have registered your service in `AndroidManifest.xml` as :

```
<service android:name="com.xxx.xx.Your_Service" />
```

Comment: Thank you, the note about AndroidManifest was actually quite helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that by just creating a BroadCastReceiver that calls your Service when your Application Boots. Here is a complete answer given by me. [Android - Start service on boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690350/android-start-service-on-boot/7690600#7690600)

If you don't want any icon/launcher for you Application you can do that also, just don't create any Activity with

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Just declare your Service as declared normally.

Answer (score 0):

When you got an sms you can start your service by broadcast receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {

            context.startService(new Intent(context,
                    YourService.class));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Unable to start ", "Service on ");
        }
```

and pls make sure you have mention the permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
```

and for sms sending and receiving you can check out this tutorial [Sending sms in android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)