# How to determine Device startup event in android

Tags: android

I want to mantain a log in my android application , log will contain the Device Started (Bootup) and Device Stop Times. Any Idea how to do this ?

I have to start my application on Bootup , But how to determine that application is started on Bootup ?

I have searched but could not find a better solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Start service on boot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690350/android-start-service-on-boot)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `BroadCastReceiver` to receive `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast. This broadcast is thrown in device startup

The receiver will be like

```
    <receiver
        android:name="ReceiverName"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

You will need to use the following persmission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

now in code write a `BroadCastReceiver` class like

```
public class ReceiverName extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          // do startup tasks or start your luncher activity
    }
}
```

Comment: yes working with I am getting this warning message: UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver (above code)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) component for this purpose. Using this you can detect various events of your device like booting.

To Detect Booting process you need to give permission in AndroidManifest.xml as below,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
```

Then you need to create a BrodacastReceiver which will handle this,

In the onReceive() method the corresponding BroadcastReceiver would then start the event,

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, WordService.class);
        context.startService(service);
    }
}
```