# Detect phone boot and network connect

Tags: android

Is it possible to
detect the when the phone boots up and connects to the network?

I want to do a network call when the

phone boots up->connects to the network(only first time after boot not always)->do network call.

I got the boot up detection figured out

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17417904/2229100

need help with the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169059/android-event-for-internet-connectivity-state-change) and also [this](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges) for Android 7.0 (API level 24)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a duplicate of many others monitoring network. Take a look at [Broadcast receiver for checking internet connection in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app) fro example. It probably handles everything you need.