# Android + OpenCV: process camera frames in a service

Tags: java, android, opencv, service

Most OpenCV examples for Android are based on a CameraViewActivity that receives, processes and displays the frames. But similar to [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690350/android-start-service-on-boot) I want to build a service that is started when the Android device boots. The service should access the camera and do some continously image processing.

Can anyone tell me how to initialize the camera by OpenCV for this scenario? Or any link for samples?

Comment: It is interesting for me as well. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes and no. I could not find any solution using the OpenCV framework for initializing a camera and grabbing its frames. But you can use the default Android camera implementation in a service and convert the frames to OpenCV Mat and use it for image processing then.

Comment: How do you do this? I need a `SurfaceView` and a `SurfaceHolder` in order to get the preview frames, and I don't know how to have this in a service. In other words, how do you create a preview from a service?

Comment: I posted part of my code as an answer. See below.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found several posts that explained how to do it. Basically you have to create an empty and invisible SurfaceView on the Android Camera and buffers for the preview frames. Here's part of my code.

Here's an interface that I wrote, because we do switch between local hardware and remote network cameras.

```
public interface ICamera {

    boolean supportsRegionOfInterest();

    void connect();

    void release();

    boolean isConnected();
}
```

Here's the code for the local camera that works without a visible Activity. It receives the frames in a separate thread.

```
public class HardwareCamera implements CameraAccess.ICamera,
        Camera.PreviewCallback {

    // see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html for more
    // details

    private static final boolean USE_THREAD = true;

    private final static String TAG = "HardwareCamera";
    private final Context context;
    private final int cameraIndex; // example: CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT or
                                    // -1 for
    // IP_CAM
    private final CameraAccess user;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private int mFrameWidth;
    private int mFrameHeight;
    private CameraAccessFrame mCameraFrame;
    private CameraHandlerThread mThread = null;
    private SurfaceTexture texture = new SurfaceTexture(0);

    // needed to avoid OpenCV error:
    // "queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!"
    private byte[] mBuffer;

    public HardwareCamera(Context context, CameraAccess user, int cameraIndex) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cameraIndex = cameraIndex;
        this.user = user;
    }

    // private boolean checkCameraHardware() {
    // if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
    // PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
    // // this device has a camera
    // return true;
    // } else {
    // // no camera on this device
    // return false;
    // }
    // }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance(int facing) {

        Camera c = null;
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        int cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        int index = -1;

        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == facing) {
                try {
                    c = Camera.open(camIdx);
                    index = camIdx;
                    break;
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,
                            String.format(
                                    "Camera is not available (in use or does not exist). Facing: %s Index: %s Error: %s",
                                    facing, camIdx, e.getMessage()));

                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        if (c != null)
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Camera opened. Facing: %s Index: %s",
                    facing, index));
        else
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not find any camera matching facing: " + facing);

        // returns null if camera is unavailable
        return c;
    }

    private synchronized void connectLocalCamera() {
        if (!user.isOpenCVLoaded())
            return;

        if (USE_THREAD) {
            if (mThread == null) {
                mThread = new CameraHandlerThread(this);
            }

            synchronized (mThread) {
                mThread.openCamera();
            }
        } else {
            oldConnectCamera();
        }

        user.onCameraInitialized(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);
    }

    private/* synchronized */void oldConnectCamera() {
        // synchronized (this) {
        if (true) {// checkCameraHardware()) {
            mCamera = getCameraInstance(cameraIndex);
            if (mCamera == null)
                return;

            Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

            // Camera.Size previewSize = sizes.get(0);
            Collections.sort(sizes, new PreviewSizeComparer());
            Camera.Size previewSize = null;
            for (Camera.Size s : sizes) {
                if (s == null)
                    break;

                previewSize = s;
            }

            // List<Integer> formats = params.getSupportedPictureFormats();
            // params.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);

            params.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(params);

            params = mCamera.getParameters();

            mFrameWidth = params.getPreviewSize().width;
            mFrameHeight = params.getPreviewSize().height;

            int size = mFrameWidth * mFrameHeight;
            size = size
                    * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(params.getPreviewFormat())
                    / 8;

            this.mBuffer = new byte[size];
            Log.d(TAG, "Created callback buffer of size (bytes): " + size);

            Mat mFrame = new Mat(mFrameHeight + (mFrameHeight / 2),
                    mFrameWidth, CvType.CV_8UC1);
            mCameraFrame = new CameraAccessFrame(mFrame, mFrameWidth,
                    mFrameHeight);

            if (this.texture != null)
                this.texture.release();

            this.texture = new SurfaceTexture(0);

            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewTexture(texture);
                mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
                mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
                mCamera.startPreview();

                Log.d(TAG,
                        String.format(
                                "Camera preview started with %sx%s. Rendering to SurfaceTexture dummy while receiving preview frames.",
                                mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        // }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onPreviewFrame(byte[] frame, Camera arg1) {
        mCameraFrame.put(frame);

        if (user.isAutomaticReceive() || user.waitForReceive(500))
            user.onPreviewFrame(mCameraFrame);

        if (mCamera != null)
            mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
    }

    private class CameraAccessFrame implements CameraFrame {
        private Mat mYuvFrameData;
        private Mat mRgba;
        private int mWidth;
        private int mHeight;
        private Bitmap mCachedBitmap;
        private boolean mRgbaConverted;
        private boolean mBitmapConverted;

        @Override
        public Mat gray() {
            return mYuvFrameData.submat(0, mHeight, 0, mWidth);
        }

        @Override
        public Mat rgba() {
            if (!mRgbaConverted) {
                Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, mRgba,
                        Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV12, 4);
                mRgbaConverted = true;
            }
            return mRgba;
        }

        // @Override
        // public Mat yuv() {
        // return mYuvFrameData;
        // }

        @Override
        public synchronized Bitmap toBitmap() {
            if (mBitmapConverted)
                return mCachedBitmap;

            Mat rgba = this.rgba();
            Utils.matToBitmap(rgba, mCachedBitmap);

            mBitmapConverted = true;
            return mCachedBitmap;
        }

        public CameraAccessFrame(Mat Yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
            super();
            mWidth = width;
            mHeight = height;
            mYuvFrameData = Yuv420sp;
            mRgba = new Mat();

            this.mCachedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        public synchronized void put(byte[] frame) {
            mYuvFrameData.put(0, 0, frame);
            invalidate();
        }

        public void release() {
            mRgba.release();
            mCachedBitmap.recycle();
        }

        public void invalidate() {
            mRgbaConverted = false;
            mBitmapConverted = false;
        }
    };

    private class PreviewSizeComparer implements Comparator<Camera.Size> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Size arg0, Size arg1) {
            if (arg0 != null && arg1 == null)
                return -1;
            if (arg0 == null && arg1 != null)
                return 1;

            if (arg0.width < arg1.width)
                return -1;
            else if (arg0.width > arg1.width)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }

    private static class CameraHandlerThread extends HandlerThread {
        Handler mHandler;
        HardwareCamera owner;

        CameraHandlerThread(HardwareCamera owner) {
            super("CameraHandlerThread");

            this.owner = owner;

            start();
            mHandler = new Handler(getLooper());
        }

        synchronized void notifyCameraOpened() {
            notify();
        }

        void openCamera() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    owner.oldConnectCamera();
                    notifyCameraOpened();
                }
            });

            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "wait was interrupted");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsRegionOfInterest() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() {
        connectLocalCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void release() {
        synchronized (this) {

            if (USE_THREAD) {
                if (mThread != null) {
                    mThread.interrupt();
                    mThread = null;
                }
            }

            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                try {
                    mCamera.setPreviewTexture(null);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not release preview-texture from camera.");
                }

                mCamera.release();

                Log.d(TAG, "Preview stopped and camera released");
            }
            mCamera = null;

            if (mCameraFrame != null) {
                mCameraFrame.release();
            }

            if (texture != null)
                texture.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConnected() {
        return mCamera != null;
    }
}
```

The camera frame is taken from the OpenCV samples. It's responsible for converting the raw byte-array into OpenCV mat structures. The implementation of that interface is inside the code above.

```
public interface CameraFrame extends CvCameraViewFrame {
    Bitmap toBitmap();

    @Override
    Mat rgba();

    @Override
    Mat gray();
}
```

Comment: I'm using a 4.2. Jellybean on a Nexus 5 tablet and on ODROID-U2 which is an embedded computer running Android.