# Android stand alone service

Tags: android, android-intent, service, background-process

I just started working on an application for Android, to be specific - a service.

I would like to create a service (background service, forcing itself to run, hidden, so it can't be shut down). and I don't have idea on how to construct it. How it is then launched and how to make it fit to those requirements. It needs to start running from the Android start, so I guess it would be created similarly to system services (or as a system service).

You may ask why I need that - I would like it to periodically send some data to MySQL DB without any user interaction - therefore it needs to run continuously.

It would be really helpful if You could give me a great start, a tutorial maybe or some structure drawing with crucial information.

One more thing - I am targetting Android 2.3, but if it's impossible, I'd like it to be the lowest possible Android version.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Well if you are using a service you should know that as long as your application is running foreground it is ok but if it's paused android can kill the service any time to take ressources back. If you want it to stay alive no matter what you have to start it with StartForeground() and use START_STICKY. Do some googleing there are plenty of tuto for doing that. And know that every foreground services MUST have a notification always present as long as it is running to inform the user of it existance.

Comment: @Yume117: A `START_STICKY` service will not "stay alive no matter what", as the user can still stop the service from running, using Settings, or perhaps a manufacturer-supplied task manager.

Comment: Of course you are right you can't force a service to run "no matter what" I totally agree. But using those tips you can "increase" it's life time. Maybe using AlarmManager you can restart the service every Xmin or Xhour if it's been killed, but it is not very best practice i would say...

Comment: what about using NDK? Will a native service complete with those requirements?

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to create a service (background service, forcing itself to run, hidden, so it can't be shut down).

Fortunately, this is not possible. Users have control over their device, not you, and they can shut down whatever they want.

> It needs to start running from the Android start, so I guess it would be created similarly to system services (or as a system service).

System services are part of the operating system and cannot be created via the Android SDK.

> You may ask why I need that - I would like it to periodically send some data to MySQL DB without any user interaction - therefore it needs to run continuously.

It does **not** need "to run continuously". That would be a singularly poor implementation.

If you want to do something periodically, use `AlarmManager` for the scheduling. The work should be done by an `IntentService`, so the service *can go away when the work is done*, so you are not tying up memory all of the time and making it *more* likely that the user will shut you down. If you plan on waking up the device out of sleep mode to do the work, you should look into `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, or possibly [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful&ei=V0c8Usz_M5TI4AOjj4GYDg&usg=AFQjCNG72hXtdajjsqnYixgBdYDNmOxhlw&sig2=_s0lWPvOOpADXTnd-W1MhQ&bvm=bv.52434380,d.dmg).

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer. At first, it is going to be used by my  child, so I am going to install it and can do whatever it takes to make it hidden.

Second thing, alright, that's pretty bad, but have to live with it.

Third pard - I do need to run it continuously, because the final version is meant to collect data packs from GPS (with maybe 1-2 sec interval) and send it every X min to database.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I found the answer myself, but thanks for help to any of You who contributed :)

I am aware that it's not the best approach, but I need to do it that way, so I found [this](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-make-android-service-unstoppable.html) for running a service and restart after stopped, also found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690350/android-start-service-on-boot/7690600#7690600) for start the service/application on boot.

Both tested and worked for me.

I hope it is going to help anyone who needs it.

Comment: this tips works fine for me, it's not very nice to have many pieces of code to perform that, but works fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this service to be executed daily??
 You need alarm manager .. that will help you in to start you service with android start and will execute your service after specified time delay.. You can specify the time for delay also. Dont forget to add permissions for alarm manager in manifest file.

Comment: well, I need it to be running and send data to my database every 5 minutes (this may change).