# How do i publish a persistent live card in the Glass GDK?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

So I've got my live card working with the v12 GDK.  It responds to a voice trigger and then sits there until the user stops it.

However, I can't determine how to create an *always present* live card which always remains on the left side of the timeline.  Some apps already do this, the Settings app and Weather app, for instance.  But I've been unable to make the same happen for my app; I can't find any hook on Glass start like the GlobalAlarmReceiver for normal Android apps.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

To make a live card that will remain in the timeline even if the user reboots the device, you may want to try the [techniques described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7690600/307266) to register a broadcast receiver that detects when the system is booted and you can start your service from there.

Your users will still need to use a voice trigger to start it once after installing it, though (either that, or reboot their device, which is even less desirable). This is because on Android, the `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` broadcast that gets sent when an application is installed doesn't get sent to the application that was just installed.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible then?

Comment: Not automatically when the user enables your application on MyGlass, no. But feel free to file a feature request in our issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list

Comment: Issue filed:

    https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=370&thanks=370&ts=1390149348