# failed to start service on boot

Tags: java, android, boo

my App has a camera photo backup service. When user turned on the service, it will automatically backup  sd-card photos to remote server. But when user shut down android OS and boot again, the backup service failed to start again.

I read many articles online, I did exactly the same as they described, but turned out to be wrong.
Maybe some experts here can help me. see the code below.

In android manifest.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>       package="com.seafile.seadroid2"
>       android:versionCode="20"
>       android:versionName="1.0.1"
>       android:installLocation="internalOnly">              
>     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />    
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />        
>     <application
>         android:allowBackup="true"
>         android:name="com.seafile.seadroid2.SeadroidApplication"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">            
>         <receiver android:name=".OSBootReceiver" >
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
>             </intent-filter>
>         </receiver>
>         <activity android:name="com.seafile.seadroid2.BrowserActivity"
>                   android:label="@string/app_name"
>                   android:theme="@style/Theme.SeafileTheme"
>                   android:launchMode="singleTask">
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>             </intent-filter>
>         </activity>
>         <service android:name="com.seafile.seadroid2.transfer.TransferService" > </service>
>         <service android:name="com.seafile.seadroid2.monitor.FileMonitorService" > </service>
>         <service android:name="com.seafile.seadroid2.sync.CameraUploadService" > </service>            
>     </application>
> </manifest>
> ```

OSBootReceiver class

```
 public class OSBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "OSBootReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "boot to notic receiver");

        Intent cameraUploadIntent = new Intent(context,
                CameraUploadService.class);
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        boolean isUploadStart = settings.getBoolean(
                BrowserActivity.CAMERA_UPLOAD_SWITCH_KEY, false);
        if (!isUploadStart) {
            return;
        }
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "boot to start service");
        context.startService(cameraUploadIntent);
    }

}
```

this it the complete project with start service error [on github](https://github.com/Logan676/seadroid/tree/rc)

I tried to reboot os many times, but didnt fond any log printed! any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check **Boot Completed** action in `onReceive(.....)` like

```
if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

   Logs("ON Boot completed with System BroadcastReceiver");

  //do your job

 }
```

and also set `<intent-filter>` like to your `OSBootReceiver` in `manifest.xml`

```
       <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I changed the code according to your description, turned out still failed to print logs.

Comment: @LoganGuo No No it's not possible. you still doing some mistake...post your all manifest and some more code...

Comment: @LoganGuo or refer this [stackoverflow.com/questions/7690350/android-start-service-on-boot?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690350/android-start-service-on-boot?rq=1)

Comment: @M D I already posted more code, if you refresh you can view it. After comparing the reference you supplied, I found the order of Service and Receiver Tag is not the same, should I move the Receiver tag to the bottom of Service tag? Thanks by the way

Comment: my testing phone is Samsung p3110

Comment: @LoganGuo Move your root receiver after activity and services and try.... i am not sure about this.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61333/discussion-between-m-d-and-logan-guo).

Comment: @M D thanks for your advice, I found that I didn`t register the receiver yet. now it works.

Comment: @M D by the way, I didn`t figure out how to register the receiver here yet, do I need to register the receiver in launcher activity. Also I think I already registered it in Manifest.xml, so could you please show more info about your meaning of registration we talked about yesterday. I will really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Correct `receiver` entry in your Manifest should be just

```
<receiver android:name=".OSBootReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
What is package name used in file OSBootReceiver.java

If package name is  com.seafile.seadroid2,


**change Receiver in manifest as below:**

<receiver android:name="com.seafile.seadroid2.OSBootReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

I added like above, and i am getting Boot completed broadcast intent.

For testing purpose, 
add Toast message in onRecieve method:


    public class OSBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "OSBootReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "boot completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e(DEBUG_TAG,"boot completed intent received");
}
}
```

Comment: this is the complete project in github:https://github.com/Logan676/seadroid/tree/rc