# Service forced stopped after BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I'm developing a Service that runs in the background and listens to notifications from a server. This Service has to start when the device boots. Somehow, I can not get it to work. The Service starts, but then it's stopped by the system.

Even following the schema proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7690600/981393, after the Service is started I see that it's being **force stopped** by the system.

So I'm wondering, is this the way is supposed to be?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Receiver**

```
public class SSBankBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "SSBankBootReceiver";
private static final long PERIOD = 60000 * 1;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Boot completed.");

        startTestService(ctxt);
    }
}

private void startTestService(Context ctxt) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting test service...");
    Intent i = new Intent(ctxt, TestService.class);
    ctxt.startService(i);
}
```

**Service**

```
public class TestService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "TestService";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    printMessages();

    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

private void printMessages() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while ( true) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Imprimiendo nuevo mensaje...");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".DashboardActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="<package>.service.SSBankBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="<package>.service.TestService"></service>

</application>
```

**Log**

```
11-04 19:38:04.916: I/ActivityManager(276):   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{41135258 u0 <package>/.service.TestService}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i fix this exact same problem :

```
    //do things you want
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT; //this is the ANSWER
```

Comment: Nop. Same error, but it's inconsistent. Sometimes the service keeps running and sometimes it's killed. Could it be that the OS it's deleting it because it needs memory?

Comment: @Federico Strange. This code solved my problem. Please post your service and broadcast receiver code if possible

Comment: @Federico But in my case, the error is consistent (always forced stop after reboot)

Comment: @Federico your code looks good. Do the force stop always happen right after you reboot the device? If its happened randomly, its possibly your service is killed by the OS.

Comment: Yes, it happens right after reboot. And I think it has something to do with this http://zadjhu.blogspot.com/2013/08/better-to-add-some-delay-before.html, if I add an AlarmMannager and 30 seconds delay (random number) it works without problems.

Comment: @Federico Im afraid its the only solution for now. I think this bug only occurred in a few devices (mine not).