# Trouble starting my Android service on boot

Tags: java, android

### I am having trouble starting my service on boot.

I have a broadcast receiver that should get called whenever the device boots up (it isn't) , and it starts my service. Unfortunately, the service isn't starting!

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android) page, read every answer, and followed every step...but it is still not working. I want to start my service whenever the phone restarts/powers on.

---

```
package curlybrace.ruchir.myApp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class BootUp extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "myTag";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.

        Log.v(TAG, "Hooray! Received boot! :) "); //Sadly I am not getting this message

        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);



    }
}
```

But my service still wont start. Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="curlybrace.ruchir.myApp"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />




        <receiver
            android:name=".BootUp"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECIEVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**I have been stuck on this for the last three days,** and I would really appreciate your help. Why is my service not starting on boot?

Comment: Just to check-  you have launched an Activity in your app at least once, right?  (if not, the apk is in a stopped state and will not receive broadcasts

Comment: @GabeSechan yes I have already opened the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I define my auto start receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.AutoStartReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Notice the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`

Comment: So I remove the receive?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia yes. Replace your entire `<intent-filter>` section with what I pasted and it should work fine.

Comment: Then what does recieve boot completed do?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I'm not sure (Google it) but it doesn't matter because 'android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED' is the correct action :-D

Comment: Alright, thanks. This will start my service on restart and on power off -> power on, right? Will this get called any other times? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `BroadcastReceiver` doesn't get called because the action of the broadcast is no `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` and not `RECIEVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`.

If you fix that your Receiver should work.

Your code to start the service looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".