# Broadcast receiver - how to?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

i'm just practing and i'm trying to make simple brodcastreceiver in Android Studio.

I have this manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.maurelio.flipcover">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver android:name="SensorReceiver">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

</application>
```

and i have this SensorReceiver.java

```
package org.maurelio.flipcover;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by maurelio on 22/03/18.
*/

public class SensorReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

When i try to run the app i get: "Default Activity not found".
I tried also invalidate chache/restart, nothing change.

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found

Comment: i cant see your activity in Manifest !! he is trying to run an app without an activity @ADM :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Start service on boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690350/android-start-service-on-boot)

Comment: You dont have any activity in application. Your application contain only receiver. When you run app system will try to find default activity as entry point of app.

Comment: Sorry to all, but reading this:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html
i was thinking that if i set a receiver in the manifest that is the default activity, also reading here
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm
Where is MainActivity in manifest of second link?

Comment: An "activity" is specifically an `Activity` subclass. Since Android 3.1, you need to have at least one to allow the user to launch your app after installation. Until then, your app is in the _stopped_ state, and the Receiver you have registered in the manifest won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you do not have a default activity defined in your manifest.xml file.

Normally you would have a MainActivity defined there.

In the tutorial you used, there is no MainActivity in their manifest, but I think that is their mistake.  However, they do describe the MainActivity class itself.

I would suggest using Android Studio to create a new project from a blank template such as "Basic Activity" and then slowly adding your code to that new project.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty activity in your current project and add the below part to your manifest

```
 <activity android:name=".YourActivityName">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

change the activity name with your new activity