# Run an IntentService without an Activity

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, background-process

I have a service which needs to run permanently in the background, but as soon as the activity closes so does the *IntentService* created by it:

```
public class CAS extends IntentService {
  public CAS() {
    super("CAS");
  }

  Sensor accelerometer;
  SensorManager sensorManager;
  CA cA= new CA();

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

    sensorManager.registerListener(cA, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    LocationManager locationManager = GlobalFunctions.LocationLibrary.getLocationManager(this);

    cA.start(this, locationManager);
  }
}
```

How can I go about making this class run indefinitely in the background, even starting up when Android does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the service with a BroadcastReceiver

Here is a [sample](https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android) program on the same.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7690600) answer for restarting the service when device is rebooted

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) of BroadcastReceiver