# Run Service Automatically After Reboot

Tags: android

I would like my service (Toast message for now) to run automatically after boot up and have the following code:

Mainfest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />            

<receiver
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
```

BootUpReceiver

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

{
        /****** For Start Activity *****/

        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);

        /***** For start Service  ****/
        /*
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(myIntent);
         */
    }
}
```

}

MyService

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public int counter=0;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        startMyOwnForeground();
    else
        startForeground(1, new Notification());
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void startMyOwnForeground()
{
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "example.permanence";
    String channelName = "Background Service";
    NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
    chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
    chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert manager != null;
    manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build();
    startForeground(2, notification);
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    startTimer();
    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stoptimertask();

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
    broadcastIntent.setClass(this, Restarter.class);
    this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}



private Timer timer;
private TimerTask timerTask;
public void startTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            Log.i("Count", "=========  "+ (counter++));

            //THIS PART RUNS EVEN AFTER APP IS KILLED
            if (counter > 10)
            {
                counter = 0;
                Log.i("Count", "runBGProcess");     //if not already running

                //Bring Toast To Foreground
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "runBGProcess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000); //
}

public void stoptimertask() {
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Intent intent;
Intent mServiceIntent;
private MyService mYourService;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //SERVICE CALL
    mYourService = new MyService();
    mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, mYourService.getClass());
    if (!isMyServiceRunning(mYourService.getClass())) {
        startService(mServiceIntent);
    }
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service is Running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service is not Running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    //stopService(mServiceIntent);

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
    broadcastIntent.setClass(this, Restarter.class);
    this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

- When app is started and I kill the app the service continues to run - OK
- When app is in foreground and I restarted phone, the app will appear in running apps menu (by pressing square button) but the service not running - NOT OK
- When app is killed from foreground, even though service will continue to run, rebooting phone in this state will not run the service let alone show the app from the running apps menu - NOT

Is there a way my Toast "runBGProcess" (from MyService class) can run in background after bootup without initiating the app first (it must run the service in background / hidden after reboot), so even if the app is killed at run time, it should run automatically at next boot in the background.

Comment: you can find the solution for 'running service on boot' in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7690600/6003772)

Comment: @HamidSj The solution seems to be working on an emulator but not on real device