# Send notification while application is destroyed

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I have set up a Work Manager to send a notification on my device. Currently notifications are shown only when my app is started. How would i achieve getting those notifications while application is not created?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service) to run your application in background. And you need to edit your Manifest to auto-launch it at startup.

Have a look at [this other Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690350/android-start-service-on-boot) for a complete example.

Also I suggest you read [these restrictions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) about starting activities from the background.

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel satisfied with the answer, please consider accepting it. Thank you.