# How to start a program on boot in Android 10?

Tags: android

I'd like to start a program in Android 10 right after boot in a generic way. Can anyone shed light on this?

I tried writing a app for Android Studio that handles BOOT_COMPLETED event that calls the app, and the app is supposed to print hello World after boot. But it did not do anything in Pixel a.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690350/android-start-service-on-boot

Answer (score 0):

**Android 9 and below**

Register BroadcastReceiver in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".StartOnBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

StartOnBootReceiver code:

```
class StartOnBootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) {
            val activityIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            activityIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            context.startActivity(activityIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

On system startup, your BroadcastReceiver will be launched, then it will launch MainActivity.

**Android 10 and above**

Starting from Android 10, the startActivity method only works when it is called by an application that is in the foreground. Therefore, you may need to request the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
```

Now request the REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSION if android version is above 10:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
      val intent = Intent(
          Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
          Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
      )
      startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSION)
}
```

Once the permission is granted you can again use the startActivity method from your BroadcastReceiver.