# Command to know when device turned on first time

Tags: android

Is there a way to know what time my device has been turned on?

Something like an adb command or something like that?

any idea?

Comment: You can use broadcast receiver for more detail you can use following link [stackoverflow.com/questions/7668836/how-to-start-a-service-when-the-android-device-is-turned-on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668836/how-to-start-a-service-when-the-android-device-is-turned-on)

Comment: Does anyone read questions before they mark duplicates anymore? How does adb have anything to do with starting a service when the device has turned on? They have nothing in common at all.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, I agree with the previous commenter, I do not think this is a duplicate. Adb has nothing to do with starting a service at boot. This question is quite vague, yes, but not a duplicate. I think you should reopen.

Comment: I reopened the question yet for me it sill qualifies for closing as "unclear what you are asking".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know what at what *time* your device was turned on, you can go into Settings > About Phone > Status, and there you have an "Uptime" entry, which tells you how long the device has been on for. Subtract that from the current time, and you have  the time the device was turned on.

You can also run the `uptime` command from adb or terminal, see [this answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/95766/).

---

If you want to do it in code, you can do something like:

`System.currentTimeMillis() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();`

Check this for more details:
[How to get Android system boot time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342301/how-to-get-android-system-boot-time)